# Applying css styling to an element class inside an external iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, elementor

I have the following code nested inside an iframe on a wordpress website using elementor

```
<div class=“container mt-4”>
<b>Current Public Events</b>
<br>
<b>Dec</b>
<table> = $0
    <tbody>
        <tr class=“event” onclick=“window.open(‘scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False’)”></tr>
        <tr class=“event” onclick=“window.open(‘scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False’)”></tr>
        <tr class=“event” onclick=“window.open(‘scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False’)”></tr>
        <tr class=“event” onclick=“window.open(‘scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False’)”></tr>
        <tr class=“event” onclick=“window.open(‘scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False’)”></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and i want the tr elements to be styled so they are 20% wide and to be side by side (inline) as currently they are just listed one below the other with no styling.

I have tried the following

```
.event{width:20%!important;display:inline-block!important;}
```

but that does not do anything

```
table > tr .event{width:20%!important;display:inline-block!important;}
```

does nothing

the website is https://sennencommunitycentre.co.uk and the iframe content is located directly underneath the main slider images with the headline "current public events" and i'd like to style the events container to take up the whole width of the page with each event tr being 20% wide if possible?

Many Thanks

Comment: After researching it some more it doesn't look like this is possible using css on an external iframe :(

Comment: no, you can't apply css to iFrames

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this. If it works for you then it's good:

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .container table {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .container table tbody {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .container table tr {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: auto;
    }

    .container table tr td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container mt-4">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="event" onclick="window.open('scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False')">
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="event" onclick="window.open('scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False')">
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="event" onclick="window.open('scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False')">
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="event" onclick="window.open('scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False')">
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="event" onclick="window.open('scheduler/ViewBooking/6255627?dm=False')">
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```